# get last day of previous year from sybase ase

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sap-iq

I need to set a where condition to the last date of previous year. 
I looking for the solution using dateadd function but i can not figure it out. This code gives me the last day of current month. But how to get the last day of december last year '2015-12-31' of have tried different ways but it all gives me odd results.

```
declare @today datetime
select @today=getdate()
select convert(varchar(10), dateadd(dd, -day(dateadd(mm, 1, @today)),dateadd(mm, 1, @today)),101)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Sybase ASE, not ASA or IQ:

```
declare @lastyear smallint, @dec31 datetime
select @lastyear = datepart(year,getdate()) - 1
select @dec31 = convert(datetime, convert(char(4), @lastyear) + "1231")
select @dec31
```

This produces

```
 --------------------------
        Dec 31 2015 12:00AM
```

@lastyear contains 2015, the last year, then text "2015" is concatenaded into "20151231", which is the desired date in AAAAMMDD char format. Next step converts it into date, datetime or smalldatetime. @dec31 stores that result.

Answer (score 0):

select convert(datetime, convert(varchar, datepart(year, getdate()) - 1 ) + '/12' + '/31')

---

Dec 31 2015 12:00AM

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      DATEADD(DD,-1,DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, '', GETDATE())+1, ''))
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.